# BASH IP Address Check

Tags: macos, bash, validation, shell, ip-address

I am working on a BASH shell script where I need to be able to check and see if the IP address returned from:

```
dig $HOSTNAME +short
```

is within a particular subnet or not.  For example, if part of 192.168.10.x or 10.130.10.x then do z else do y.

I am not sure how to manipulate or check the IP address after I have it stored in a variable so that I can build out the logical test described above.

Comment: possibly related: [check if a bunch of ip addresses belongs to given network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435606)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following code to make it work:

```
if [[ "$IP" == *10.130.10.* || "$IP" == *192.168.10.* ]]; then
   mount code goes here
fi
```

Thanks for everyone's help and explaining things to me to allow me to further learn about scripting. It is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If your subnets are full class C then you can just do a substring check:

```
if [ ${IP#192.168.10.*} == ${IP} -a ${IP#10.130.10.*} == ${IP} ]
then
    echo "not in either subnet"
else
    echo "in one of the subnets"
fi
```

Edit: Note, this of course doesn't validate that the IPs are valid, but it alleviates the need for external tools.

Comment: +1, for this case, it's the most sensible solution, though it isn't really based on the idea of ip address and subnet.

Comment: This looks like an excellent idea.  However, I seem to be struggling to get it to work since it does not appear to be validating the IP from the variable that it passed to it.

Comment: I just receive an error that states " [: too many arguments " when I try to use this snippet of code.

Comment: @John: That means you're not using bash. Or you've got some POSIX-ly correct mode set. Try Changing `-a` to `] && [`. If you're actually not using bash, please fix your question and remove the 'bash' tag.

Comment: @Derobert - I am using a Macintosh with OS 10.6.8 on it.

Comment: @John: Did the `] && [` work? You can try `echo $BASH_VERSION` to see if you're running bash. If you are, you'll get something like `4.1.5(1)-release`; otherwise, you'll probably just get blank.