# BASH Check if exists within variable

Tags: macos, bash, shell, scripting, ip-address

I am working on a script that will be used to map network drives.  However, we only want to attempt to map the drive if the machine has a particular IP address.  Listed below is a code snippet that we are trying to get working.

```
#!/bin/sh

IP="dig $HOSTNAME +short"

if [ $IP == *10.130.10.* ]; then
    mount drive commands here
fi

if [ $IP == *10.130.11.* ]; then
    mount drive commands here
fi
```

I am not able to get the check for IP to work.  Is there a better way to check to see if a variable contains a string, in this case part of an IP address?

The information listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970251/bash-ip-address-check) posting was not helpful since it did not work.

Comment: I don't think that `[` can test for complicated substrings. It can only do string equality, but with a single `=`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Indeed it cannot. In bash, you can use `[[ $VAR == *pattern* ]]` (note double-bracket). Or you can use `case` in any POSIX-compatible shell (including bash).

Comment: @derobert: Oh, nice, I didn't know about `[[` -- thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a "bash" tag on the question, but the shebang says /bin/sh.  Which do you actually want to use?

Actually, first things first.  The way you're setting IP doesn't work, since it never runs the dig command; you need either backquotes or `$( )` to do that:

```
IP="$(dig $HOSTNAME +short)"
```

Now, for the test; there are a number of ways to do it.  This should work in all shells:

```
case "$IP" in
    *10.130.10.*)
        mount drive commands here
        ;;
    *10.130.11.*)
        mount drive commands here
        ;;
esac
```

Note that if the mount commands are the same for the two subnets, you can use `*10.130.10.*|*10.130.11.*)` as the pattern to match.

If you're actually using bash, you can use its `[[ ]]` conditional expression to do the matching more like how you had it:

```
if [[ "$IP" == *10.130.10.* ]]; then
    mount drive commands here
elif [[ "$IP" == *10.130.11.* ]]; then
    mount drive commands here
fi
```

As above, if the mount commands are the same, you can do a single conditional with `if [[ "$IP" == *10.130.10.* || "$IP" == *10.130.10.* ]]; then`.  Also, the double-quotes around `$IP` aren't actually necessary in this particular case, but I always make a habit of double-quoting variables unless there's a reason not to.

Comment: @ Gordon - This works really well.  Thank you for your excellent explanation, it really helps me to understand some of the reasons that things were not working and how to do better next time.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @ Gordon - Out of curiosity, how should I fix the opening of my script in relation to the "bash" tag and the shebang?

Comment: The first line of a script (starting with `#!` aka sharp-bang or shebang) tells the OS what interpreter to read it with -- bash, perl, python, etc.  For bash, use `#!/bin/bash`. `#!/bin/sh` runs it under whatever "plain" Bourne shell is installed on your computer, which may or may not support any of bash's extensions.  So if you want to use bash extensions like `[[ ]]`, it's safest to start the script with `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @ Gordon - Excellent information.  Thank you so much for the help, I have learned a lot and really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
[[ "${IP/10.130.10./}" = "$IP" ]] || mount
```

Comment: That seems to match on any IP that I try for the first part of your expression.

Comment: I was testing with the following --- if [[ "${IP/10.130.10./}" = "$IP" ]]; then echo Happiness! fi

Comment: @John: No, mind the inverted logic: `echo Unhappiness` @Michael: Nice use of Bash variable gymnastics :-)

Comment: @ Kerrek - does that mean I messed it up with my test?

Comment: @John, I use `||`, which means *if false*